# Delete instruction in MySql

Tags: php, mysql

While deleting a row that doesn't exist in *mysql* , it returns true with msg = 0 row deleted.
the question is how can I do something in *mysql* and getting a false value in php.

It's my code:

```
function deletePost( $id ) {

    $q      = "DELETE FROM $this->postsTable where id='$id'";
    $result = $this->bool_query( $q );
    echo $result;

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Check the affected row count

Comment: @juergen d : I tried it.but is delet a post the affected row is 0. and if there no post the affected row is 0 too.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can do that counting the number of rows affected in a previous MySQL operation.

- With PDO you can use [PDOStatement#rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) to do that.
- With mysqli is [mysqli_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/it/mysqli.affected-rows.php).

Be aware that just because `DELETE` doesn't remove any rows, it doesn't mean that the query fails. If you want assert that, you have to count the rows affected.

Comment: If `delete` remove a row, and the affected row is `0`, then you are doing something wrong. If you want help, we need the code.

Comment: No. you can try it with myphpadmin page in your localhost. if you delete a row it doesn't any affect on rows.

Comment: If you remove a row, it _does_ affect a row. That's how it works. If you're so sure about that, then you obviously don't need our help. I won't try to convince you - but if you wan't someone else help, then provide the relevant code to him.

Comment: my say is right.I solved my problem see the answer.I'll be happy if you vote it.

Comment: why did you ask this?

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer I had to get the count of posts, once before delete and once after Delete, and check if the before count is greater than after count if is so result is true and if not result is false.

Comment: this works, but it's definitely not the right answer just use affected_rows as suggested by the answer above

Comment: Delete in mysql has not any affect on rows. believe this.

Comment: @ahmad, it doesn't. You'd need to choose the right transaction isolation level. OP is just joking with us.

Comment: @Federkun IQ , I'm using the code in my file and it works very well.

Comment: I am not sure if this is a joke or not, but I am going to flag this answer to let a moderator deal with it as it promote bad practice and it really shouldn't represent an answer to this question

Comment: @ahmad: moderators are not concerned with answer correctness, that's what voting is for.

Comment: I reported it anyway, and I am down voting this too as it hit a nerve